# Finding a relation between $P$ and $P^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

I encountered a challenging problem on a mock test today:

Let $x$ be an $n \times 1$ matrix.
We define $$P = -(x^Tx)^{-1}\cdot(xx^T)$$

Now there were $4$ options, something like $P^2 - P = O$ where $O$ is the null matrix
and $P^2 + P = I$, I'm afraid I don't exactly remember all of them.

My approach was to take $$x = (a_{1} , a_{2}, \dots a_{n})^T$$
and then figure out P first, which came out to be:

$$|x|^2 P = - (xx^T)$$ where $xx^T$ is a big $ n \times n$ matrix which I'll admit, I couldn't figure out the latex to type, so let's call it $A$.

($|x|^2$ here means : $\Sigma_{i = 1}^{i = n}a_{i}^2$)

$$\implies |x|^2 P = -A$$
I then tried to find out $P^2$ and I got:
$$|x|^{(2n - 4)} P^2 = A$$

I fear that my calculations are incorrect as I'm unable to find any obvious relation between the two here.

It would be a great help if someone could point me in the right direction!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $x^\top x$ is a constant. How can we use that property when expanding our expression for $P^2$ in terms of $x$?

> $$P^2 = [-(x^\top x)^{-1} x x^\top]^2 = (x^\top x)^{-2} (x x^\top) (x x^\top) = (x^\top x)^{-2} x (x^\top x) x^\top = (x^\top x)^{-2} (x^\top x) x x^\top$$

Comment: Aaaaaaah. I was making a mistake here. $x^Tx$ can just be taken out of that product, wow.

Comment: So that would mean that $P^2 + P = O$, right? I marked the correct answer by intuition yaay.

Comment: But .. $P$ has a $-$ sign? I'm confused.

Comment: Ah, you're right---I overlooked the $-$ sign when reading the question statement. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another way to answer this question is by recognizing that $P$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $-\text{Proj}_{W}$ where $W=\text{span}(x)$.

Comment: @MatthewH. could you please point me to some resources where I can read more about this? I'm curious as to how $W$ = span$(x)$. Does $x^T x$ always mean the span of $x$? And I'm clueless about Projection matrices and linear transformations in general :(